# use two <input type="radio"> for one input field in angular

Tags: angular, angular5

I have two radio buttons in Angular 5 project and i want to pass value to `formControlName` and `placeholder` of `input` depends on radio button value. How can i solve this problem?

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="list-inline">
      <div class="list-inline-item">
        <div class="radio-outer">
          <input id="contact-email" name="input" type="radio" value="email" checked />
          <label for="contact-email">E-mail</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="list-inline-item">
        <div class="radio-outer">
          <input id="contact-phone" name="input" type="radio" value="phone" />
          <label for="contact-phone">Phone</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="input" name="user-contact" placeholder="jon_walker@gmail.com">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the placeholder you could use `[placeholder]="someAngularVar"` instead of `placeholder="static value"`, for the formControlName it won't work, you need to do it differently by creating two components.

[Here is a stackblitz solution suggestion.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49941935)

Answer (score 0):

this solved my issue, i used angular reactive-form and custom `onSelectionChange()` method:

```
  onSelectionChange() {
        if (this.contactFormGroup.controls['contactType'].value === 'phone') {
          this.contactFormGroup.controls['phone'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
          this.contactFormGroup.controls['email'].setValidators([]);
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.contactFormGroup.controls['phone'].updateValueAndValidity();
            this.contactFormGroup.controls['email'].updateValueAndValidity();
          }, 0);
        } else {
            this.contactFormGroup.controls['phone'].setValidators([]);
          this.contactFormGroup.controls['email'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.contactFormGroup.controls['phone'].updateValueAndValidity();
            this.contactFormGroup.controls['email'].updateValueAndValidity();
          }, 0);
        }
      }
```